# Is it possible to make your own winapi function like getpixel to work on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, getpixel

Is it possible to make your own winapi function like GetPixel that work on windows, if it is what steps should make?

Comment: "your own winapi function"? Did you make a different version of [GetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144909(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: yes man different version of your own GetPixel not using windows.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. One way or another, you will end up accessing some part of the WinAPI. You may provide utility wrappers, and many parts of the WinAPI already are such wrappers. But you can't entirely avoid it. At the heart of Windows are datastructures that you just can't access directly.

But why do you want this?

Comment: well sometimes you need function which is not supported by winapi, so i think to make your own. Thanks for answer you give me point, ... when you say hearth of datastructures that you cant access directly, what is that datastructures?

Comment: @tonni: Well, you can of course write `AcmeCompanyPrintPayroll()` which obviously isn't in the WinAPI. But most functions neither are nor belong in the WinAPI. As for the data structures inside Windows, that would include e.g. the data structure behind each `HWND`. There are probably thousands.